# Installing packages (via cabal) from "local hackage"

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

Is it possible to get cabal to

- Download a particular package source, including all dependency packages sources.
- At a later stage (when internet connectivity can no longer be relied upon) install these packages via cabal, from the locally downloaded files,  automatically in the right order so that the desired package is build?

I know that you can use `cabal unpack` to view the source of a particular package, but I am not sure how to achieve above. Also note that in this post [Can't get cabal update to work inside corporate network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420439/cant-get-cabal-update-to-work-inside-corporate-network) it was mentioned that this could be done, but the instructions were not specific enough for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cabal help | grep fetch`:

```
fetch        Downloads packages for later installation.
```

Example:

```
$ cabal fetch unbound
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading RepLib-0.5.3.1...
Downloading type-equality-0.1.1...
Downloading unbound-0.4.1.1...
```

Running `cabal install unbound` at a later stage won't require Internet access.